# Sending custom JsonObject with child object to server fails

Tags: java, android, json, playframework, retrofit

I am trying to POST an object from my Android client to my Play Framework Java REST API to persist to the database.

I am using Retrofit to perform API calls, and Realm for local device storage. JSON is handled using the Gson library in the client device.

I have a custom class to convert my object to JSON before sending, because if I don't do this, any child objects will include extra information such as *columnInfo* which will not be recognised on the server and it will not be able to convert the object to it rightful entity.

**Server Stacktrace message**

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "columnInfo" (class models.UserTbl), not marked as
>   ignorable (5 known properties: "dateCreated", "id", "name", "email",
>   "dateUpdated"])

**Custom Serialization class**

```
public class UserBookSerializer implements JsonSerializer<UserBook> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(UserMovie src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        final JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("id", src.getId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("bookId", src.getBookId());
        jsonObject.addProperty("user", String.valueOf(context.serialize(src.getUser()))); // here is the issue
        jsonObject.addProperty("isSaved", src.isSaved());

        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

Above is my attempt, however it has not been successful. Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize classes really easy with gson, let's say that's the Json you want to get on the server

```
{  
  "name":"never",
  "age":5,
  "data":{  
    "id":"2fds4",
    "locale":"us"
  }
}
```

You write the following structure

```
class User {
   String name;
   long age;
   Data data;
}

class Data {
   String id;
   String locale;
}
```

then you just pass the instance of `User` to your retrofit, it will serialize it.

Comment: Yes this is what I originally did, I did not override any default serialization, but it still included extra information, such as columnInfo, and this is why I turned to the approach in my question, which also does not work.

Comment: If you want to exclude signalization of a field you can add `transient` modifier

Comment: I do not want to exclude it from serialization, the problem is it includes extra properties that are not user defined - see below what the is sent to the server, it does not include the properties I desire.

`"user" -> "{"columnInfo":{"emailIndex":2,"idIndex":0,"nameIndex":1,"passwordIndex":3,"indicesMap":{"email":2,"name":1,"password":3,"id":0}}}"`

Comment: Could you place elaborate in your question, I'm having hard time understanding your intent

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the class UserMovie and use Gson's `@Expose` annotation to explicitly mark the attributes you want to send. It should be used along with `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` when you create the Retrofit instance.

https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html